# Surjective homomorphism from a ring to its localisation?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be an algebraic variety, $R$ the ring of regular functions on $V$, and $P$ a polynomial. So the localisation $R_P$ is the ring of regular functions on the Zariski-open subset $O$ of $V$ where $P$ does not evaluate to zero. Now as far as I understand, since there is an injective embedding $O \rightarrow V$, there must be a surjective homomorphism $R \rightarrow R_P$. What does this homomorphism look like in terms of $R$ and $R_P$?

Or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2):

You have indeed misunderstood. $O\to V$ is a monomorphism (the correct categorical generalization of injective: a left-cancellable map), so its dual $R\to R_P$ is an epimorphism (the correct categorical generalization of surjective: a right-cancellable map), but ring epimorphisms are not necessarily surjective maps. Heuristically, what $R\to R_P$ being an epimorphism means is that all the behavior of any ring homomorphism out of $R_P$ is determined by the behavior of that homomorphism on $R\subset R_P$ - this makes sense, since elements of $R_P$ are of the form $\frac{f}{P^n}$ for some $n$, so the image of that under a ring homomorphism $\varphi: R_P \to S$ should just be given by $\frac{\varphi(f)}{\varphi(P^n)}$, and the numerator and denominator are both things you would know if you only knew how $\varphi$ worked on $R$.

As for what this map looks like, the map is given by sending $f\in R$ to $\frac{f}{1}\in R_P$.